# XML to SQL Server Parsing Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm parsing below XML and trying to fetch all the attributes/values of  node.

```
declare @XBL xml='
<Root>
      <Department>
             <Employees>
                <Employee type="temp">
                 Jason
                </Employee>
                <Employee type="perm">
                 Roy
                </Employee>
             </Employees>
      </Department>
      <Department>
             <Employees >
                <Employee type="temp2">
                 Kevin
                </Employee>
             </Employees>
      </Department>
</Root>'

SELECT  
    [Type] = XC.value('(@type)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
       [Name] = XC.value('(../Employee)[1]' , 'varchar(30)')
FROM
    @XBL.nodes('Root/Department/Employees/Employee') AS XTbl(XC)
```

**Output of above query** gives me all the attributes but with first value only(Jason).

```
Type  Name 
temp  Jason
perm  Jason
temp2 Kevin
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Type  Name 
temp  Jason
perm  Roy
temp2 Kevin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're after:

```
SELECT XBL.E.value('@type','varchar(25)') AS [Type],
       XBL.E.value('(./text())[1]','varchar(30)') AS [Name]
FROM @XBL.nodes('Root/Department/Employees/Employee') XBL(E);
```

Note the use of `/text()` as well. When returning data from inside a node, adding `/text()` actually improves the performance of the query.

*Edit: Also, based on your sample xml, the value returned for `[Name]` would actually be `'{Line break}                 Jason{Line break}'` (Obviously replace the line break with the actual character). Is that what you intend, or do you want the whitespace and line breaks/carriage returns removed as well?*

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the first Employee child of the parent Department:

```
[Name] = XC.value('(../Employee)[1]' , 'varchar(30)'
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To select the current Employee, use:

```
[Name] = XC.value('(.)[1]' , 'varchar(30)')
                   ^^^^^^
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23596)